# Checking timestamp with iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

I am trying to check the existence of timestamp for a given signature of a PDF file.
So far I came to this code:

```
RandomAccessFileOrArray random = 
    new RandomAccessFileOrArray(new File("temp.pdf").getAbsolutePath());

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(random, null);
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<?> names = af.getSignatureNames();

//this are the signatures?
for (Object o : names){

    AcroFields.Item item = (Item) af.getFields().get((String)o);

    //this is the class for verifying the signature, 
    //how do I get it from the item?
    PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = null; //XYZ ??? 

    Calendar signingDate = pdfPKCS7.getTimeStampDate();
}
```

I apparently got access to the signature, but I should get to PdfPKCS7 class for verifying the signature. Does anyone have any idea how can I get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `AcroFields` method `verifySignature(String name)` which returns a `PdfPKCS7` object for continuation of the verification.

The JavaDocs of that method shows an example of its use:

```
KeyStore kall = PdfPKCS7.loadCacertsKeyStore();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("my_signed_doc.pdf");
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList names = af.getSignatureNames();
for (int k = 0; k < names.size(); ++k) {
    String name = (String)names.get(k);
    System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
    PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
    Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
    Certificate pkc[] = pk.getCertificates();
    System.out.println("Subject: " + PdfPKCS7.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
    System.out.println("Document modified: " + !pk.verify());
    Object fails[] = PdfPKCS7.verifyCertificates(pkc, kall, null, cal);
    if (fails == null)
        System.out.println("Certificates verified against the KeyStore");
    else
        System.out.println("Certificate failed: " + fails[1]);
}
```

Here you can easily add additional code using the `PdfPKCS7` instance.

Ceterum censeo... unless you are bound to that ancient iText version (e.g. due to compatibility or license concerns), though, you should consider updating to a current version.

Comment: I had this solution before but it wouldn't compile. I downloaded the itext version and found out that af.verifySignature(name) worked.  It was a third party version I was using that was modified. Thanks.